# Run GraphDB behind Apache Proxy

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, graphdb

I run grapdb as a standalone server. The service starts on http://localhost:7200.
I need to configure an Apache redirect to graphDB workbench, to access it through port 80 :

```
    ProxyPass /graphdb http://localhost:7200
    ProxyPassReverse /graphdb http://localhost:7200
```

However, when accessing http://server/graphdb, all the loading of CSS and javascript fails because they are loaded from http://server/css/x, or http://server/webjars/y, instead of http://server/graphdb/css/x or http://server/graphdb/webjars/y.

Is it possible to access GraphDB workbench behind an Apache proxy and what would be the correct configuration for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At present this is possible only if the root of both the external (Apache) and internal (GraphDB) side is the same. In your case the external one is /graphdb and the internal one is /. We've planned support for specifying an explicit external URL in GraphDB 7.1. As a temporary workaround you can create an Apache redirect of the kind:

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:7200
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:7200
```

and assign it to a separate virtual host, e.g. graphdb.your-domain.xx, that will be used only to access GraphDB.

Comment: Pavel, the external url thingy wasn't added yet, or was it? BTW ` ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` directives are missing the final `/` in `http://localhost:7200/`: so `ProxyPass / http://localhost:7200/` and `ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:7200/`. Would you mind editing the post (SO asks the edits to be 6+ character for non-authors and I don't want to add other stuff ;))

Comment: Hmmm, wea re at GraphDB 8.6.1 currently and I don't think this is supported yet - can you confirm ?

Comment: What is the status on this? Still not supported in 8.9.0?

Answer (score 3):

Following the questions above - the parameter is "graphdb.workbench.external-url"

You can pass it to the process with: -Dgraphdb.workbench.external-url=http://...

Answer (score 0):

The documentation now (9.8) says that *graphdb.workbench.external-url* is a legacy property. Use: *graphdb.external-url*